# Android Emulator control from keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard

I'm working android project.So I'm using Android Emulator for this step.
But when project requires input I'm using Emulator keyboard.Is there any method for enter from keyboard to android emulator without android's emulator keyboard?
How to enable PC's keybord for write text or password on Emulator?

Comment: When setting up your AVD, you can select `Hardware keyboard present`

Comment: Mapping for all keys is not available(as far as I know). Here is a resource page that may help you: [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

Comment: @kabuto178 I clicked new button in the Android Virtual Device Emulator but I didn't see "Hardware keyboard present".
How can I find "hardware keyboard present"?

Comment: I just checked, the option should be there, after clicking on `new` you will see a checkbox option there that enables the keyboard.

Comment: @kabuto178 When I clicked the new button I cannot see this checkbox.Is there different AVD manager.If yes , I have to old version

Comment: I saw answer but I cannot see this checkbox in my AVD manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I just checked, the option should be there, after clicking on new you will see a checkbox option there that enables the keyboard